# assign values to symbols in python debugger (pdb)

Tags: python, pdb

Using `pdb.set_trace()`, I am trying to debug a series of expression in which `j` is used as an indexing variable. statements such as `j = 0` are not allowed since `j` is a reserved symbol for `pdb`. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
!j = 0
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html):

> [!]statement
>
> Execute the (one-line) statement in the context of the current stack frame. The exclamation point can be omitted unless the first
>   word of the statement resembles a debugger command.